# inequality involving lifts of a positive oriented homeomorphism of the circle

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, dynamical-systems

Let $\pi: \mathbb R \to S^1$ be the natural projection and let $f:S^1 \to S^1$ be a positive oriented homeomorphism. We say that $F: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is a lift of $f$ is $\pi \circ F = f \circ \pi$ and it's continuous.

I want to prove that if $x,y \in \mathbb R$ are such that $|x-y| < 2$ then $|F^n(y)-F^n(x)| <3$. The book used the fact that if $|x-y| < 2$ then $| [x]-[y]| \le 2$ But I don't know how to prove that last statement ( $[x]$ denotes the floor function )

Comment: Its not true: $x=0.9$, $y=2.1$, $|x-y|=1.2<2$, but $|[x]-[y]|=2$. But $|[x]-[y]|\le 2$ is true in general, if $|x-y|<2$.

Comment: Thanks and how Can I prove that first step D:?